# How to sum category item's quantity value in excel? Like sum every day expense.

Tags: excel

I just wanna sum every day expense like following table:
[image]

In Google Spreadsheet,

```
D column:     =UNIQUE(A2:A) 

E2            =SUM(FILTER($B$2:B;!A2:A=D2))  
E3            =SUM(FILTER($B$2:B;!A2:A=D3))  
...
```

How to create same table on Excel?

Comment: @gtwebb that works but assumes the unique dates are already in D:D. I think the OP needs to know how to do that as well. I recommend making a pivot table as a one-step solution.

Comment: You could get D:D dates by using `=MIN(A:A)` in D2 then in D3 copied down `=IFERROR(SMALL(A:A,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&D2)+1),"")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No formula, just a few clicks:

1. click anywhere in the data table in columns A:B
2. click Insert Ribbon > Pivot table and OK
3. click and drag "Day" from the field list into the Row Labels area
4. click and drag "expense" from the field list into the Values area.

[image]